# Ошибка в DNS записях

Tags: windows, dns

Недавно у меня появилась проблема. Когда я заходил по имени, я попадал на другой компьютер, но, и заходя с настоящего имени, попадал на тот же компьютер. Подскажите, где искать ошибки в настройке. И как вообще такое могло случится.

Comment: Ойёй... недостаточно сведений. Кто DNS-сервер? На какой машине? Есть ли локальный\удалённый DNS-кэш явно или неявно (например, в Outpost или nscd)?

Comment: Стандартный DNS сервер на Win Server 2003.

Comment: А разъяснить вопрос можно? Что такое "заходить по имени"? "Заходить с [не]настоящего имени"? А то получается вопрос про какой-то "бурбулятор" - вы угадайте, что у меня за проблема, и скажите, как её решать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
```

Скорее всего, проблема какая-нибудь локальная...

Comment: Пробовал не помогает. Проблема решается через некоторое время.

Comment: хм.. а IP DHCP раздаёт?
что скажет nslookup <имя компа> ?

Comment: IP DHCP раздает, nslookup не пробовал.

Comment: попробуйте из cmd набрать nslookup имякомпа, и скожите что будет в результате.. (заодно сами возможно поймёте проблему)

Comment: Пока не удалось повторить баг. Может подскажите что на сервако посмотреть чтобы изменить?

Comment: Можно посмотреть, какие записи есть в днс... Больше ничего в голову не приходит. )

Comment: В DNS были дублирующие записи естественно.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc759204(WS.10).aspx
<br>
http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc776907(WS.10).aspx
<br>
Не тот случай?

Comment: Я думаю это оно. Благодарю.